# React Native Window @0.72 how window resize lock

Tags: react-native, react-native-windows

I have d/f issue, react native windows @0.72 how i lock resize window
when i add these line

Build failed with message
4:6>F:\Ahsan\newDesktopRn\windows\x64\Debug\newDesktopRn\AppxManifest.xml : error APPX0501: Validation error. error C00CE014: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 35, Column 8, Reason: Element '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10}ApplicationView' is unexpected according to content model of parent element '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}Application'. [F:\Ahsan\newDesktopRn\windows\newDesktopRn\newDesktopRn.vcxproj]. Check your build configuration.
Command failed. Re-run the command with --logging for more information.
error Command failed with exit code 2302

i search on chatgpt

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Package
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
   xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
   xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
   IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp">

<Applications>
  <Application
  Id="App"
  Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
  EntryPoint="newDesktopRn.App">

  <uap:VisualElements
    DisplayName="newDesktopRn"
    Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png"
    Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png"
    Description="newDesktopRn"
    BackgroundColor="transparent">

    <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png"/>
    <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
    <uap:InitialRotationPreference>
      <uap:Rotation Preference="landscape"/>
    </uap:InitialRotationPreference>

  </uap:VisualElements>

  <uap:ApplicationView
    uap:ResizeMode="NoResize"
  />

  </Application>
 </Applications>

</Package>
```

When i try this, App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 35, Column 8, Reason: Element '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10}ApplicationView' is unexpected according to content model of parent element '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}Application